# Weird characters (´╗┐) at the start of a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, encoding

I am working with batch files in Windows, using both Notepad, and Notepad++. When I run the batch files, which all start with `@echo off`, I see the first line (when running on two separate machines) reading `´╗┐@echo off`, and then all the REM lines below it appear as well.

I have tried changing the encoding in Notepad++, but it claims they are already at UTF-8 encoding, which appears to be correct.

What do I need to do to get these files to run properly?

Comment: @luu my question is about notepad++ specifically

Comment: Note that regular Notepad, when saving with UTF8, does not allow to save without BOM, and will add those characters.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It looks like the DOS ASCII encoding of the Byte Order Mark for UTF-8 `(0xEF 0xBB 0xBF)`:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

In Notepad++ try encoding it as "UTF-8 Without BOM" or as plain ASCII. I think the use of BOM for UTF-8 is discouraged for this reason, it's not exactly backwards compatible with ASCII.

Comment: Absolutely right, except the 'DOS ASCII' is DOS code page 850, as shown by experimention in Python: `>>> print u'\ufeff'.encode('utf8').decode('cp850')
´╗┐`

Comment: @deltab Ah, good find. I wasn't sure what the encoding was specifically called, just that I hadn't seen the line-art characters `╗┐` since the days of MS-DOS 5/Windows 3.11. Modern Windows must run batch files with that encoding for compatibility?

Comment: I ran into this when using Visual Studio to create a new text file.

Answer (score 14):

Turns out it needs to be set to [ANSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_ANSI_code_page#ANSI_code_page) encoding to work properly. To set this, I chose **Encoding**->**Encode in ANSI**.

To figure this out, I tried to create a batch file from the command line.

```
echo @echo off > batch.bat
echo REM Some comment... >> batch.bat
echo echo Hello world! >> batch.bat
```

I then opened this file up in Notepad++, and checked the encoding in the lower right corner, which read **ANSI as UTF-8**. I don't know why it adds that last bit, but it seems to work now.

Comment: ANSI is not really an encoding. Presumably it refers to your Windows system's *default [code page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page)*. That will vary from one system to another, depending on configuration.

Comment: This is not correct.  The BOM is a character set encoding artifact.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Who's incorrect, me or Cody?